# socketio use callback tips create_client.<locals>.test() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ack'

Tags: python, python-socketio

server code:

```
  def test_call_back(text):
         print(text)
  sio.emit('test', 'test call back', callback=test_call_back)
```

cliend code:

```
@sio.on('test')
def test(data,ack):
    print(data)
    ack()
```

run wrong tips:

```
create_client.<locals>.test() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ack'
```

How should I use callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using the JavaScript client documentation and applying that to the Python client. The Python client is not a clone, so please use the Python documentation instead. For callbacks: https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html#event-callbacks.

Example ack that returns two values to the other side:

```py
@sio.event
def my_event(sid, data):
    # handle the message
    return "OK", 123
```